# css positioning to align the div horizontally

Tags: css

I'm working the following HTML [(also in this fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/kgVKw/5/).

```
<div id="block1" class="Box"  style="width: 15%; height: 67; overflow-n: scroll;">
    block 1
</div><br/>
<TABLE CLASS="BODY" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" RULES="NONE"> table 1 </TABLE>
<div id="block2" style="width: 20%; height: 67;top: 0; position: absolute;left: 25%;">
    block 2
</div> <br/> 
<table CLASS="BODY" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" RULES="NONE" > table 2</table>
<div id="block3" style="width: 22%; height: 67;top: 0; position: absolute;left: 50%;">
    block 3
</div><br/>
<table CLASS="BODY" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" RULES="NONE" > table 3</table>
<div id="block4" style="width: 25%;top: 0;  position: absolute;left: 75%; height: 67; display: inline-block;">
    block 4
</div><br/>
<table CLASS="BODY" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" RULES="NONE" > table 4</table>
```

I want the four blocks named block 1 block 2 block 3 block 4 to come horizontally without changing of tables position.

Now it is fine.All the blocks are in proper position.

But if some other div is present like  can paste this `<div> position </div>`  at the top of the fiddle.Only block 1 coming to the next line automatically since I dint give positioning for block 1.I want other block 2,3,4 also to come in same line,if some div is present.Can we acheive this through any CSS properties?

Note:Each Div is Under 4 different functions

Comment: “ like can paste this `<div> position </div>` at the top of the fiddle” — perhaps you could paste that into a copy of your first fiddle, and link to the copy to demonstrate how it doesn’t work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [**myFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/czFfV/) just wrap with a div positioned relative..

Comment: Hi almost I reached with your answers but my each div is under 4 different functions.How to do for this?

Comment: what do you mean by 4 function?

Comment: Means my coding is like function1{<div id="block1"> block 1</div><TABLE> table 1 </TABLE>
} function2 { <div>block 2</div> <table> table 2 </div>} Each div is like a block ,,Here how can I use the wrapper div?

Comment: so is it fyn wid u if u make evrytin in a table or u need divs?

Comment: No i cant get your question.table and div will be seperate.I want the divs that is blocks to come horizontally even Am placing one div in top.Wat you given in fiddle ws right,but I cant use the wrapper div since each div is in seperate functions.Hope u got it..

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have block2 - 4 absolutely positioned. This takes them out of the element flow, ignoring the div in the beginning.

Use either `float` or `display:inline-block` to align the divs horizontally without ignoring any markup "in front of them".
Alternatively you could use an additional wrapper div which has `position:relative`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time.. I tried with inline block,it is not working out.If am using in 4 different functions how to achieve thriugh float and inline block

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kgVKw/6/ 
Is that what you want to achieve? Your code was very over-the top, all you need is that if so

Comment: Hi thanks for your fiddler..With this my table position have to be fixed since all my div is in 4 different functions but here it is changing